# Ruby rails error Invalid Switch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

ashamed to say, i got home decided to follow a tutorial and got stuck very early on. I'm running rails 3.1.1 on windows and attempting the tut from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

If you look at 4.2 it tells us to run a command: `$ rm public/index.html` - which in windows i think is just in cmd type `cd blog` and then its just `erase public/index.html`

But i get the error returned: `Invalid Switch "index.html".`

Anyone who can shed some light i would be much appreciative. I can't beleive im stuck already!

Thanks
M

Comment: I know you already had your question answered but I think you mean that you're running `rails 3.1.1`, not `Ruby 3.1.1`.  The most recent version of Ruby is 1.9.3 and it was just released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that in windows you have to use backslash instead of slash in unix-like systems. Use `erase public\index.html`

Comment: Wow thankyou, something i didnt know. Thanks again, i cant believe i didnt know that. Onwards i go :)